# Show detailed error info to some kind of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On a rails 2.3 application I want to show the detailed error exception information if `@user.is_admin?` is true. Otherwise show the generic error on `500.rhtml`.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ApplicationController, rescue_from StandardError and in that method, render a view where you print out the exception message and backtrace.

```
class ApplicationController
  rescue_from StandardError, :with => :show_exception

  def show_exception(e)
    @e = e
    render "global/show_exception"
  end
end

# app/views/global/show_exception.html.erb
<h1><%= @e.message %></h1>
<pre>
  <%= @e.backtrace %>
</pre>
```

That should do the trick. The other option is to have a before_filter that checks to see if the user is an admin, and then sets the application configuration for `consider_all_requests_local` to true if so.

```
before_filter { Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = current_user.try(:is_admin?) }
```

Comment: What could I do to use first solution but still logging errors to production.log?